# SwiftUI - pass data to different views

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working on an App which has 4 different views. The main view (**ContentView**), an **AddView**, an **EditView**, and a separated **DataView** with a class where I pass all the data by an **ObservableObject** to the other views.

In the main view I have a list of items. In the **AddView** I add items to that list and from the **ContentView**. I would like to be able to edit the added items by using a navigation link. So from the main view I would like to go to **EditView**, change the values and go back to the **ContentView** again where I see the changed values.

Would you use **ObservableObject** for doing that or do I need EnvironmentObject? Because at the moment **EditView** is not working, I can't pass the data from **ContentView** to **EditView**, all the textfields on the **EditView** are empty, the values do not get passed over. It works to pass the data from **AddView** to **ContentView** but then not from **ContentView** to **EditView**.

Can someone tell me how the data has to be linked to all the views?

Comment: Use `@EnvironmentObject`. It allows all those views with this added to share the same object containing the shared data. If you want me to post an answer for an example, let me know.

Comment: Would be great if you could post an example for my project with a main view, add view and edit view. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `@EnvironmentObject`. It allows an object to be shared, which is very important for sharing data to other views.

I am using a `Shopping` object in this example. This app will act like a shopping list. This whole project is available of GitHub [here](https://github.com/George-J-E/ShoppingListSwiftUIExample).

I really hope this is useful, as it took quite a while. This is just a *general* example of how to use `@EnvironmentObject` effectively between `View`s.

The app looks like this:

[image: How the app looks]

---

#### Creating the project

**<sup>(can be downloaded through GitHub, see above link)</sup>**

**1:** First, in your `SceneDelegate.swift`, replace:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
```

with:

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(Shopping())
```

**2:** Xcode will be complaining for now about `Shopping` not being made yet, so we will fix that next:

```
class Shopping: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var list = [
        ShoppingItem("Bread", quantity: 1),
        ShoppingItem("Milk", quantity: 2),
        ShoppingItem("Eggs", quantity: 12)
    ]
    
    func addItem(_ item: ShoppingItem) {
        list.append(item)
    }
}


class ShoppingItem: Identifiable {
    
    var name: String
    var quantity: Int
    
    init(_ name: String, quantity: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
    }
}
```

**3:** Next, we want the main content, `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var shopping: Shopping
    @State private var newItem: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(shopping.list) { item in
                    NavigationLink.init(destination: EditView(currentItem: item)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(String(item.quantity))
                            Spacer().frame(width: 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if newItem != nil {
                    TextField("New Item", text: $newItem.bound, onCommit: {
                        if !self.newItem!.isEmpty {
                            self.shopping.addItem(ShoppingItem(self.newItem!, quantity: 1))
                        }
                        self.newItem = nil
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Shopping List")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.newItem = ""
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

**4:** Along with this `extension` to let optional `@State`s work (credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041232/9607863), although this has been simplified):

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    var bound: String {
        get {
            return self ?? ""
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**5:** And then finally - the `EditView`, to allow you to edit the name of the item in the shopping list:

```
struct EditView: View {

    let currentItem: ShoppingItem
    @EnvironmentObject private var shopping: Shopping
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Item", text: $name, onCommit: saveName)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray)
            .onAppear(perform: setName)
    }
    
    private func saveName() {
        shopping.objectWillChange.send()
        currentItem.name = name
    }
    private func setName() {
        name = currentItem.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will help me to get my app done :)

Comment: @Distace Glad it helped! 

Comment: I want to thank you for going that extra mile and creating a special project for your peer. Kudos to you, sir!