# How to have a shared state across swiftUI app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to sign in with Gmail on my swift UI MacOS app. I have the state object here

```
@State var sharedUser = User.shared

var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup {
          ContentView()
              .onOpenURL { url in
                  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
               }
               .onAppear {
               GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in
               if error != nil { return }
                  sharedUser.signIn(user: user)
               }
          }
     }
}
```

I see that it restores the previous sign in and I make the shared User the user it returns. Over here in the content view I have a check to see if the user is logged in

```
@State var user = User.shared

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        if user.user != nil {
            Button(action: {
                logout()
            }) {
                Text("Sign Out")
            }
        } else {
            GoogleSignInButton(action: handleSignInButton)
        }
    }
}
```

However user always returns nil, and I'm wondering how I can share the object value from the App Struct to the View.

Comment: If User is-a ObservableObject then use @StateObject instead, if not then make it such and use as stated before.

Comment: Oh wow that worked. I had User as NSObject but I changed it to ObservalbleObject. Thanks! Wish I can checkmark a comment

Comment: Inject EnvironmentObject into the app
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68876216/how-to-declare-global-state-variables-in-swiftui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your `User` type conform to `ObservableObject` (which means it has to be `class`).
2. Add `@Published` in front of all the properties (in `User`) that you want **SwiftUI** to detect changes.
3. Instead of `@State`, use `@ObservedObject`.

Comment: You should use `StateObject` instead of `ObservableObject`.

Comment: I would argue that. You have to use `@StateObject` if the view is the owner of that object, but since it's singleton, `@ObservedObject` will fit better.

Comment: Yes a singleton but the object should be called Store and have a User struct as an @Published property