# Why @EnvironmentObject but not shared global ObservableObject to views

Tags: swiftui

Sorry I am new in Swift, I have a curious question about global sharing `ObservableObject`

I saw this answer and understand `@EnvironmentObject` here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59919052/9585130

Instead using `@EnvironmentObject` why we don't use like this?

```
class Person: ObservableObject {
    let shared = Person()
}
```

Then anywhere in `view` we can use like below and no need `EnvironmentObject` any more?

```
struct BookList: View {
    @ObservedObject var persionViewModel = Person.shared
    ...
}
```

```
struct BookView: View {
    @ObservedObject var persionViewModel = Person.shared
    ...
}
```

Is it impact to memory leak issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using @EnvironmentObject injects this dependency into a view and it’s subviews.
If at some point the root view (the one the dependency was injected into) gets removed, the environment object will (should) also be deallocated.

So @EnvironmentObject storage is a bit like a service registry rather than a singleton.